# UNMET PEER Dependency webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Not sure how to fix this...I've been fighting with it for a couple hours. See below, a screen shot of the error. Any ideas are hugely appreciated! Please let me know if you need more info.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but first comment didn't solve my problem. This is the the boiler plate I want to use. And would like to learn how to get around this kind of problem for the future

Comment: My mistake. Error is saying that you have webpack installed version `2.1.0-beta.13`, but 2 packages need other webpack v1 `1.4.0` & `1.9.11`.

Comment: Again, I appreciate the suggestion. But I don't think that is correct. The warnings are optional dependencies I believe, and shouldn't affect functionality.

Comment: Incorrect. See [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) `peerDependencies` section and the NOTE: section under that.  those 2 warnings mean the package wont work right with the webpck you have installed, `2.1.0-beta.13`

Comment: Ok cool, I'll check review the docs

Comment: It doesn't mean it won't work right with that version, it means it's not been *tested* with that version. It might work, it might not, all depending on wether the changes that prompted webpack to release a 2.x version were in parts of the API the boilerplate was using. I know that's a nitpick but it's important to differentiate :)

Comment: Thanks Ivarni. Can you share links to documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmet WebPack peer dependencies issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294555/unmet-webpack-peer-dependencies-issues)