# Unmet WebPack peer dependencies issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-install

So i have a wierd issue, i am trying to do an npm install on a react/redux boilerplate solution i found on github however i am getting some unmet peer dependency issues. The super wierd thing though is that the way I read it, none of these are an issue... what am i missing?

```
    npm ERR! node v4.4.5
    npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
    npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

    npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.21 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
    npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer babel-loader@6.2.5 wants webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
    npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-beta.3 wants webpack@^2.1.0-beta
    npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer sass-loader@4.0.1 wants webpack@^1.12.6 || ^2.1.0-beta
    npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-middleware@1.6.1 wants webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
    npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dashboard@0.1.8 wants webpack@*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the version if npm you are running, they were very strict about peer dependencies.

In npm 3+ this will let you download webpack 2.2RC without your install failing.

You can also you yarn as well! `npm install -g yarn`.
Then simply run `yarn install`!!!